# Is it possible to print multiple copies to PDF using CUPS/lpr

Tags: cups, lpr

I'm testing an application that sends PDFs to a printer, and it may request that multiple copies are printed, sending a command like

```
/usr/bin/lpr -T Document Title -# 10
```

I don't have access to a physical printer, so I'm using the CUPS generic virtual printer to "print" PDFs to disk.  This works, however regardless of the number of copies requested, it only prints a single file.

```
$ echo hello > hello.txt
$ lpr -P PDF -T test -# 2  hello.txt 
$ ls PDF/
test.pdf
```

Is there a configuration that will respect the copies argument, for example creating `hello-1.pdf` and `hello-2.pdf`?

- Distribution is Debian 9.
- cups: 2.2.1-8+deb9u6
- cups-bsd: 2.2.1-8+deb9u6
- cups-pdf: 2.6.1-22
- `grep MaxCopies /etc/cups/cupsd.conf` -> MaxCopies 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't such a configuration. Each time the spooler opens the output, writes the data, and closes the file. Next copy it does it again.

If you need multiple copies, print your data to PDF once, and use The PDF ToolKit, `pdftk` to multiply. Read `man pdftk`.